# Condo fan coil unit vent now blows on thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I live in a 30 year old condo, and recently had the thermostat replaced on my fan coil heat/AC unit. Previously there was no thermostat, but simply an on/off switch with different fan speeds.

Here is the problem: the on/off switch was directly below the main heating/AC vent in my living room. Now that I have a thermostat (Honeywell Suite Pro TB6575A1000) the vent just blows directly on it, skewing the temperature in the room.

I can't use the "auto" setting, because it warms the thermostat too quickly and only causes it to run for less than a minute, which is not enough time to heat my condo. So I have to run it on "low" constantly.

Essentially, I paid for a digital version of the on/off switch that I had before. Moving the thermostat is not really an option (or a costly one that I cannot afford at this time).

Wondering if there is anything I can do? A cover for the vent and/or the thermostat? Can I replace it with a smart thermostat that uses wireless sensors? Am I just stuck living with it?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] to add a picture - there are various types of vent hoods and deflectors that might work, or not, depending on the setup you have. Most vents have built in louvers that can be re-aimed, for that matter, to make them blow out more than down. You may also be able to simply find an appropriate offset from the temperature you want and the temperature you have to set on the thermostat to get what you want. So if you want 68°F/20°C you may need to set 5 or 10 degrees above that on the poorly positioned thermostat.

Answer (score 1):

Think about getting a thermostat cover similar to the one shown below from Lowe's. You can then experiment taping off the vents on the cover to regulate the operation of the thermostat.

[image]